# Cannot export 100000 rows to a variable using stuff

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to get 100,000 records in single column but get only 160 rows.I am using this to export to csv. Please help

```
     declare @STR_EXPORT_CSV nvarchar(max);
     SELECT @STR_EXPORT_CSV=STUFF(( SELECT '\r\n"'+f.UniqueId+'","'+ISNULL(f.LastName,'')+'","'+ISNULL(f.Firstname,'')+'","'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ISNULL(f.Age,0))+'","'+
 ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE,f.birthdatetime),101) +' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CONVERT(TIME,f.birthdatetime),108),'')+'","'+
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE,f.death_datetime),101) +' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CONVERT(TIME,f.death_datetime),108),'')+'","'+
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),ISNULL(f.genderName,''))+'","'+ISNULL(f.babyRefNo,'')+'","'+ISNULL(f.PresentAddress,'')+'","'+ISNULL(f.PermanentAddress,'')+'","'+ISNULL(f.vaccinationStatus,'')+'","'+ISNULL(S.Vacc_Desc,'')+'","'+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE,s.Schedule_Date),101),'')+'","'+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE,s.Actual_Date),101),'')+'","'+ISNULL(s.Vacc_Status,'')+'"' FROM ##FINAL_VACC_SCR_PATIENTS_EXPORT f 
LEFT JOIN ##VACC_SCR_SAMPLE_CARD_DATA s on S.PatientId=f.patientId
order by RegionName asc, HospitalName asc, birthdatetime desc, uniqueId desc for xml path('')),1,4,'')

SELECT @STR_EXPORT_CSV;
```

Comment: How are you selecting the data? Could be a character limit somewhere truncating the data. Is there a reason that you trying to export to CSV this way? Not using Results to File, or SSIS, or the export wizard, or BCP? There are a lot of ways of exporting to CSV that are much easier, and probably more efficient than this.

Comment: this is an existing functionality where data is being sent to the mvc controller where its exported in csv  there is a request about issue related to data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change a type at least in one `cast`, **you should cast explicitely to `varchar(max)`**,
even if your `variable` is declared as `varchar(max)` what you get out of concatenation is a string of `8000` characters.

```
declare @s varchar(max);

set @s = replicate('a', 10000);
select len(@s) as len_;
--len_
---------
--8000

set @s = replicate(cast('a' as varchar(max)), 10000);
select len(@s) as len_;

--len_
--------
--10000
```

Comment: Is this truncation not to do with the replicate function, rather than concatenation? If you concatenate @s with anything else, the resulting string is more than 8000 characters - e.g.  `declare @s varchar(max)= replicate('a', 10000); select len(@s + 'anything else') as len_;`. Similarly I can get a string of over 8,000 characters by using the same concatenation technique as the OP - [Example on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1244da160d1b2d0e2df817f3617fd924)

Comment: tried changing varchar to max whereever used but get only 162 rows.

Comment: @GarethD You misurated expression lenght, while the truncation occurs in **variable** assignment

Comment: @Jaymz What is the length of your variable when you get you 162 rows?

Comment: @sepupic the length after assigning is 27696970

Comment: after saving the result from ssms context menu, got 1170 records. The records are over 100k, when select is used i can get the result.

Comment: The limitation of varchar(max) is 2Gb, can it be that 1170 records of over 100k exceeds 2Gb?

Comment: If truncation occurred during variable assignment, I would expect the following to return 8000 to: `DECLARE @s1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE('a', 10000); DECLARE @s2 NVARCHAR(MAX)  = @s1 + @s1; SELECT LEN(@S2);` but it correctly returns 16,000.

Comment: @GarethD when i use the select statement, and saved the result in csv from ssms, the size is  26 mb

Comment: @GarethD, it's not correct, the correct length would be 20.000, but try this one: set @s = replicate('a', 8000) + 'abc';
select len(@s); it's NOT replicate to truncate the result